# I want to get 2 specific categories in wp with get_categories method

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering

I tried with `get_categories` method to solve this problem but I am getting 
whole categories list.
 I want only 2 categories.

My code:

```php
$get_parent_cats = array(
        'parent' => '0',
        'hide_empty'=> 0,   //get top level categories only
        'exclude' =>1
    ); 

 get_categories( array( 'category' => array(31,32)));

 $all_categories = get_category(31);//get parent categories
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get_terms function to get the categories as per your requirement like this

```
$terms= get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'include' => array('31', '32'),
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Comment: great its working i did one more thing taking 31,32 in an array and then took foreach and get_category($array); this also works .but you provide the correct way of doind that. thank you so much

Comment: $ar=array(33,34,31,32);
 $nn=array();
 foreach($ar as $a)
 {
 //return $a;
   
   $all_categories = get_category($a);
   $nn[]=$all_categories;
 }
  return $nn;

Comment: in this way i did jaimin. inow it is not the right way to do.

Comment: In the above $terms array you will already getting category array so you don't have to use get_category inside it